# pegrp32c.dll and pegrp32d.dll loading in different types of windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using Visual studio 2005. I want to  load pegrp32c.dll for WINXP OS version and pegrp32d.dll for WIN7 version dynamically.If the target version is WINXP i will load pegrp32c.dll anf if the target version is WIN7 theb i want to load pegrp3d2.dll How can I achieve this?

Also i dont have any idea about the above mention third party dll.
someone please expalain what the upper mention dll is how load difference version of dll to different version of windows.

I am new to asking question in SO ,so please consider some mistake .thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to determine current Windows version first using `Version Helper` functions. Then load a dll using `LoadLibrary` method. Since you have not mentioned Windows Vista, I assume, that Windows XP rules will be applied for it.

```
#include <versionhelper.h>
///...
HMODULE hLib = NULL;
if(IsWindows7OrGreater())
{
   hLib = LoadLibrary(L"pegrp32d.dll");
}else
{
   hLib = LoadLibrary(L"pegrp32c.dll");
}

if(!hLib)
   //report an error
```

If you want to link statically against this libraries, you have to create different versions of your application for Windows XP and Windows 7. You could use `WINVER` macro to determine target platform and `#pragma comment` instruction to select lib file to link against.

```
#if WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
#pragma comment(lib, "pegrp32d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "pegrp32c.lib")
#endif
```

**References:**

[MSDN Version helper API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx)

[MSDN WINVER macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx)

If you use old version of the Visual Studio you could install [latest](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) Platform SDK, or use `GetVersion` API call, declared in the `windows.h`. Be advised however, that this method could be unavailable since Windows 8.1 so that approach is not recommended.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response .

Comment: How to use VersionHelpers.h in VS2005, it is not available in VS2005 ,while using i am getting "VersionHelpers.h': No such file or directory" error

Comment: You could either install latest Platform SDK or use deprecated `GetVersion` API method.